# Proof of set identities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question asks to prove that   $$(A\cup B')\cap(A'\cup B) = (A\cap B) \cup (A'\cap B')$$ where $A,B$ are sets. How could could i approach and solve this question, and also if there are additional resources that could help me with these kind of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [distributive law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra)
$$(A\cup B')\cap(A'\cup B)=((A\cup B')\cap A')\cup((A\cap B') \cap B)\overset{(*)}=(B'\cap A')\cup(A\cap B)$$ since $(*)$ $A'\cap A=\emptyset$ and $B'\cap B=\emptyset$. Now, $$(B'\cap A')=(A'\cap B')\quad \text{ and }\quad (B'\cap A')\cup(A\cap B)=(A\cap B)\cup (B'\cap A')$$ by the commutative law (see the same link).

---

You can find more details about the rules that apply in the algebra of sets in the link above.

Comment: Thank you. The trouble I had was that I didn't know that distributive law could be used when there was no set in common.

Comment: @fifiman You are welcome, good luck with it.

Comment: But why doesn't distributive law work in this case: (A$\triangle$B)$\triangle$(A$\cap$B) = A$\cup$B     ?

Comment: @fifman I do not understand the meaning of the triangle. What does it stand for?

Comment: It is the symmetric difference

Comment: @fifiman Not all operations distribute over all other operations. The symmetric difference and the (simple) difference of two sets do not usually distribute over all other operations. But intersection distributes over symmetric difference as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

$$
x\in(A\cup B')\cap(A'\cup B)\\
\Updownarrow\\
x\in(A\cup B')\wedge x\in(A'\cup B)\\
\Updownarrow\\
[x\in A\vee x\in B']\wedge[x\in A'\vee x\in B]\\
\Updownarrow(\star)\\
[x\in A\,\wedge[x\in A'\vee x\in B]]\vee[x\in B'\wedge[x\in A'\vee x\in B]]\\
\Updownarrow(\star\star)\\
[x\in A\,\wedge\,x\in A']\vee[x\in A\,\wedge\,x\in B]\vee[x\in B'\,\wedge\,x\in A']\vee[x\in B'\,\wedge\,x\in B]\\
\Updownarrow(\star\star\star)\\
[x\in A\,\wedge\,x\in B]\vee[x\in B'\,\wedge\,x\in A']\\
\Updownarrow(\star\star\star\,\star)\\
[x\in A\,\wedge\,x\in B]\vee[x\in A'\,\wedge\,x\in B']\\
\Updownarrow\\
x\in(A\cap B)\cup(A'\cap B')
$$
where $(\star)$ follows from the distributivity of conjunction over disjunction in mathematical logic, $(\star\star)$ also follows from the distributivity of conjunction over disjunction and from the associativity of disjunction in mathematical logic (we skipped one step), $(\star\star\star)$ follows from the fact that $[x\in A\,\wedge\,x\in A']$ and $[x\in B'\,\wedge\,x\in B]$ are always false (by definition of $A'$ and $B'$) and $(\star\star\star\,\star)$ follows from the commutativity of conjunction in mathematical logic.