# The distributive property of the intersection of sets applied to the intersection of two grouped unions of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Why when the distributive law is applied to the below statement does the union of A and B' become an intersection in the second grouping in statement 1?

I would have thought that it would be as below in statement 2 that the intersection of two unions is simply the union of the intersection of the union with the first term (ie $(A\cup B)\cap A'$) with the intersection of the union with the second term: (i.e $(A\cup B')\cap B$).

> Consider $(A\cup B')\cap (A'\cup B)$. Why is
>   $$(A\cup B')\cap (A '\cup B) =((A\cup B')\cap A')\cup ((A\color{red}\cap B')\cap B) \tag1$$
>   and not
>   $$(A\cup B')\cap (A '\cup B) =((A\cup B')\cap A')\cup ((A\color{red}\cup B')\cap B) \tag2$$

Comment: The second one is correct.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @AlexR many thanks for the info on clean posts and for your answer. I do not have the points, but perhaps you can correct this answer, since it's confusing:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1026750/proof-of-set-identities/1026775#1026775

Comment: @user2422826 What is confusing about it?

Comment: Answer 1 states: (A∪B′)∩(A′∪B)=((A∪B′)∩A′)∪((A∩B′)∩B)

Answer (score 0):

The correct equation is in fact $(2)$ as you expected. Note that the $(A\cup B')$ must be considered "atomic" when applying the distributive law.
$$M_1 \cap (M_2 \cup M_3) = (M_1\cap M_2) \cup (M_1\cap M_3)$$
Here you have $M_1 = A\cup B'$, $M_2 = A'$and $M_3=B$ yielding
$$\color{red}{(A\cup B')} \cap (A' \cup B) = (\color{red}{(A\cup B')} \cap A') \cup (\color{red}{(A\cup B')} \cap B)$$